# What is wrong with my jquery loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong with this loop and I am pulling my hair out. I can't seem to get inside the if statement to save my life.

Essentially I want to loop through a parent div, check each child for a certain class, and if that class exists do something. Any suggestions?

```
$(".button").click(function() {
  $('.container').children().each(function() {
    if ($(this.element).hasClass("look-for-this-class")) {
      $(this.element).addClass("class-1")
    } else {
      $(this.element).addClass("class-2")
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Where are you getting "this.element" from?  Take off the ".element" and see what happens.

Comment: I thought that was whichever child element was currently being looped through, is this incorrect? @Taplar

Comment: Have you used `console.log` to debug your code once?

Comment: No, 'this' will reference the element.  http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: When you say that you don't know what goes wrong, it might be a good idea to describe your full expectation, and some test data for other people to use when trying to solve your problem, the typical [mcve]

Comment: Yeah, I can get inside the loop itself, but not inside the if statement

Comment: instead of the if logic, just do `$('selector.look-forclass').addClass('new class1')` and `$('selector:not(.look-forclass)').addClass('new class2')`

Comment: @Taplar, thanks that gets me inside the loop, unfortunately, $(this).addClass("class-1") is applying .class-1 to every child element, how can I apply it just to the one specific element in the loop at that moment?

Comment: That's what your logic that you have is doing.  If it is putting class-1 on all of them, from the logic you have given it would suggest they all have the look-for-this-class on them.  You can add console logs or debug to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't even need a loop:

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  $('.container > .look-for-this-class').addClass("class-1");
  $('.container > :not(.look-for-this-class)').addClass("class-2");     
});
```

```css
.look-for-this-class{color:blue}
.class-1{color:red}
.class-2{color:green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">click</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="look-for-this-class">1</div>
  <div class="look-for-this-class">2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```